# c++ function returning a custom class array gives an error

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have a class:

```
class cAsset{
  public:
     void data(int);
     int returnInfo(void);
}
```

and a function which is suppose to return an array of cAssets

```
cAsset[] myFunc(int a, int b){
   ...
}
```

The error is:

```
Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
```

What am i missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995564/function-with-return-type-array-in-c

Comment: You're missing your C++ book.

Comment: So let's [point him at one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), @LightnessRacesinOrbit.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yes, let's! Perhaps it'll be [better than the one](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) he's of course already reading before asking questions on the internet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return arrays in C++. Try returning a `std::vector<cAsset>` instead.

```
std::vector<cAsset> myFunc(int a, int b){
  std::vector<cAsset> result;
  result.push_back(cAsset(4,2));
  result.push_back(cAsset(a,b));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: interesting.  Is there any reason why?  I mean, i thought you can declare arrays, or is it just because a vector accepts a generic class?

Comment: You can declare arrays. You just can't assign to/from them, nor return them from a function. As to "why" : arrays and pointers work the way they did in C, that is, efficiently and non-intuitively.

Comment: ahh, ok.  Good to know.  Thanks for the help @Rob.  I was wondering why this occurred.

Comment: Another option, in C++11 is `std::array<cAsset, N>`, where N is a compile-time known constant.