# The return value's function when displaying it onto the screen is wrong

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I've been knocked down with this pretty simple example that seems at first but it's been giving me a lot of headaches lately. Can someone tell me what's wrong with these function?

Note: I am working with C. It is a requirement.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* telegram_input()
{
    char message[100];

    printf("Write down the telegram: ");
    gets(message);

    return message;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
}

        printf("Write your message:\n\n");
    char * myMessage; 

    myMessage = telegram_input();

        //HERE's the problem!!!!! -->
        printf("The written message is: %s.", myMessage);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I return the the value of the array to the char* pointer, this only holds the first value of the array and it is an incorrect one.
When I print it with 'printf' it shows a smile face character. How is that?
Why does this happen? If I hadn't use the above functions I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: [You can't return arrays in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995564/function-with-return-type-array-in-c). Also, `gets` is wrong: use `fgets`.

Comment: "The return value's function" - rather the function's return value?

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a local instance of a variable that is allocated on the stack. If you wanted to do it correctly there are a couple approaches. You could allocate a char array on the heap and you'll have to deallocate it after you print it. The other approach would be to return a `static const char*` and then print it. This approach is not thread safe meaning if any other thread would call this function the data in the array would of course change giving you an unexpected print out. Even another method would be to pass the destination you want to write the message to to the function which gives you probably the most control. I'm sure there are others but this should give you some ideas.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char* telegram_input_static()
{
    static char message[100];

    printf("Write down the telegram: ");
    gets(message);

    return message;
}

char* telegram_input_heap()
{
    char* message = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    printf("Write down the telegram: ");
    gets(message);

    return message;
}

void telegram_input_dest( char* dest )
{
    printf("Write down the telegram: ");
    gets(dest);
}    

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    printf("Write your message:\n\n");
    char * myMessage; 

    myMessage = telegram_input_heap();
    printf("The written message is: %s.", myMessage);
    free(myMessage);

    myMessage = (const char*)telegram_input_static();
    printf("The written message is: %s.", myMessage);

    char destination[100];
    telegram_input_dest(destination);
    printf("The written message is: %s.", destination);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks buddy! Makes a lot of sense. Both approaches seems to work corectly.
One more thing... If I return the variable's pointer without declaring it static, wouldn't have the data to remain untouched???

Comment: static means persistent not constant meaning its not on the stack, its got space reserved for it specifically elsewhere. its safer to return it as a const char* so people dont get confused and try to free it. you could always have it just a regular char* but then it gets kinda confusing because you might want to change it when the memory really "belongs" to that function for its use.

Comment: Your first example (with static) has a strong chance of causing UB if the function is called once, stores the return value, then called again, and then the value from the first call is read: it would be equivalent to modifying a const-qualified value through a non-const qualified value, which is UB.

Answer (score 0):

Message is a local variable and you are returning it which will be de allocated. You have to create pointer and send it. Then delete it in the main.

```
char* telegram_input()
{
    char *message = malloc( sizeof(char) * (100) );

    printf("Write down the telegram: ");
    gets(message);

    return message;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    printf("Write your message:\n\n");
    char * myMessage; 

    myMessage = telegram_input();

        //HERE's the problem!!!!! -->
        printf("The written message is: %s.", myMessage);

    free(myMessage);
    return 0;
}
```