# A function that returns a table of struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct call Client , and a function `initClient` that create such struct.

Now I want to implement a function that creates a `table[20000]` of this struct, but I couldn't figure out the right syntax of the returned data. Is it `Client**` or `Client[]` ?...
This is my code: `client.h`:

```
 struct sClient
 {
     int num_tel;
     int nbr_appel;
     int cout;
  };

  typedef struct sClient Client;
  Client * initClient(int num_tel, int nbr_appel,int cout);
  Client *createData();
```

and main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "client.h"

Client* initClient(int num_tel, int nbr_appel,int cout){
    Client *c = (Client *) malloc(sizeof(Client)); 
    c-> num_tel =num_tel;
    c-> nbr_appel= nbr_appel; 
    c-> cout= cout;

    return c; 
}

Client* createData(){
    // Number of clients
    #define NBCLIENT 20 
    Client* tab[NBCLIENT];
    Client *c; 
    int i,numeroTel,prixAppel;

    for(i=0;i<NBCLIENT;i++)
    {
        // Generation of a random num_tel
        numeroTel = 600000000+(rand() % NBCLIENT);   
        prixAppel = (rand() % 400)+1; 
        c=initClient(numeroTel,1,prixAppel);
        tab[i]=c;      
    }   
    return tab;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    createData();
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `createData` the variable `tab` is a *local variable*, it will cease to exist once the function returns. Returning a pointer to its first element (which is what you do) will make that pointer immediately invalid.

Comment: I have tried to return a different variable instead of tab that point to its first element , but it didn't work

Comment: The solution is dynamic allocation.

Comment: Actually my assignement says that the return type must be Client[] , is that even possible !!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well in case of a predefined array size, there are alternatives... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581061/5265292

Comment: @YaSsou A return type of `Client[]` sounds like trouble if you ask me...

Comment: Well, yes it is a predifined size, @grek40 yes it did cause me troubles in the other hands when I used Client* some problems where solved but still not working

Comment: Since you have a specific assignment, the exact wording is important... are you asked to return `Client[]`, an array of clients, an array of client pointers or something different?

Comment: An array of 20000 Clients to be exact

Comment: Is `initClient` with this function signature your invention or is it part of your assignment requirements? Some related question on array of X: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995564/function-with-return-type-array-in-c

Comment: The assignment requires this signature: struct Client[] createData() ;

Comment: For initClient yes it is in part of my assignment requirements

Comment: The only way to return a local array (which is not `malloc()`ed) safe from a function, I see, is to make it `static`. `static` extends the life-time of the local variable over the whole program life-time. Hence access after return of function is OK. On the other hand, every call of the function returns the one-and-only same instance of variable (with the same storage).

Comment: @YaSsou I mean, is this specific function signature for `initClient` required (with return type `Client*` and parameter types as 3 integers) or is it only generally required to implement some function with name `initClient`? If you are not specific down to the last detail, then you can't get good answers. If it wasn't a homework question you could get an answer that completely changes the function signatures, but since you need them, you have to explain them in detail.

Comment: No it is the specific signature

Comment: Arrays may not be passed as arguments nor returned - they decay to a pointer. Returning a local (non-`static`) array is [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) as it allows access to something for which life-time has ended. This changes if the array is wrapped in a `struct` (like demonstrated on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/y1wSgB)). **BUT**, this means copying the array (bad performance). There was a reason why K&R decided not to support arrays for arguments/return. (May be, they even considered the trick with the `struct` as "back-door".)

Comment: I see **, I just couldn't get it right :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what has been discussed in the comments (and considering that I gave some probably confusing hints) I want to show the (only) solution I see to match all requirements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int num_tel, nbr_appel, cout; } Client;

Client* initClient(int num_tel, int nbr_appel, int cout);
Client* createData();

#define NBCLIENT 20

Client* initClient(int num_tel, int nbr_appel, int cout)
{
  Client *pClient = malloc(sizeof (Client));
  /** @bug check for NULL pointer missing! */
  pClient->num_tel = num_tel;
  pClient->nbr_appel = nbr_appel;
  pClient->cout = cout;
  return pClient;
}

Client* createData()
{
  Client *clients = malloc(NBCLIENT * sizeof (Client));
  /** @bug check for NULL pointer missing! */
  for (int i = 0; i < NBCLIENT; ++i) {
    int numeroTel = 600000000 + (rand() % NBCLIENT);
    int prixAppel = (rand() % 400) + 1;
    Client *pClient = initClient(numeroTel,1,prixAppel);
    /* copy returned CONTENTS to malloc-ed array element */
    clients[i] = *pClient; /* assignment for struct-s is granted */
    /* release pClient to prevent memory leaks - it's not anymore needed */
    free(pClient);
  }
  return clients;
}

int main()
{
  Client *clients = createData();
  for (int i = 0; i < NBCLIENT; ++i) {
    Client *pClient = clients + i; /* or: &clients[i] would work as well */
    printf("%2d.: %d, %d, %d\n",
      i, pClient->num_tel, pClient->nbr_appel, pClient->cout);
  }
  free(clients);
  return 0;
}
```

Thereby, to match the required signatures the returned `struct` value of `initClient()` is copied into the array `malloc()`-ed in `createData()`. As doing it this way, the `free()` is important to prevent memory leaks as the memory of `malloc()` done in `initClient()` is neither used nor referenced afterwards.

Compiled and tested on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/7zJESh). Output was:

```
 0.: 600000003, 1, 87
 1.: 600000017, 1, 116
 2.: 600000013, 1, 336
 3.: 600000006, 1, 93
 4.: 600000009, 1, 222
 5.: 600000002, 1, 28
 6.: 600000010, 1, 60
 7.: 600000003, 1, 327
 8.: 600000000, 1, 227
 9.: 600000012, 1, 137
10.: 600000011, 1, 169
11.: 600000007, 1, 30
12.: 600000002, 1, 331
13.: 600000002, 1, 324
14.: 600000007, 1, 336
15.: 600000009, 1, 203
16.: 600000002, 1, 259
17.: 600000009, 1, 168
18.: 600000013, 1, 57
19.: 600000011, 1, 43
```

---

The temporary memory allocated in `initClient()` and free-d in `createData()` would be something which would bother me. This could be prevented with a slight change of the signature of `initClient()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int num_tel, nbr_appel, cout; } Client;

void initClient(Client *pClient, int num_tel, int nbr_appel, int cout);
Client* createData();

#define NBCLIENT 20

void initClient(Client *pClient, int num_tel, int nbr_appel, int cout)
{
  pClient->num_tel = num_tel;
  pClient->nbr_appel = nbr_appel;
  pClient->cout = cout;
}

Client* createData()
{
  Client *clients = malloc(NBCLIENT * sizeof (Client));
  /** @bug check for NULL pointer missing! */
  for (int i = 0; i < NBCLIENT; ++i) {
    int numeroTel = 600000000 + (rand() % NBCLIENT);
    int prixAppel = (rand() % 400) + 1;
    initClient(clients + i, numeroTel, 1, prixAppel); 
    /* &clients[i] would've worked as well as clients + i */
  }
  return clients;
}

int main()
{
  Client *clients = createData();
  for (int i = 0; i < NBCLIENT; ++i) {
    Client *pClient = clients + i; /* or: &clients[i] would work as well */
    printf("%2d.: %d, %d, %d\n",
      i, pClient->num_tel, pClient->nbr_appel, pClient->cout);
  }
  free(clients);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested again on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/PkjYxv). Output was:

```
 0.: 600000003, 1, 87
 1.: 600000017, 1, 116
 2.: 600000013, 1, 336
 3.: 600000006, 1, 93
 4.: 600000009, 1, 222
 5.: 600000002, 1, 28
 6.: 600000010, 1, 60
 7.: 600000003, 1, 327
 8.: 600000000, 1, 227
 9.: 600000012, 1, 137
10.: 600000011, 1, 169
11.: 600000007, 1, 30
12.: 600000002, 1, 331
13.: 600000002, 1, 324
14.: 600000007, 1, 336
15.: 600000009, 1, 203
16.: 600000002, 1, 259
17.: 600000009, 1, 168
18.: 600000013, 1, 57
19.: 600000011, 1, 43
```

Comment: If that's the solution (instead of some error in the required signatures) then the responsible teacher is a terrible person :)

Comment: @Scheff, Thank you very much it works fine, at first it gave me an error :for loop initial declaration used outside c99 But it was fixed when I moved the declaration of i outside of the loop

Comment: @grek40 Yepp. That's why I felt the necessity of an extension.

Comment: @YaSsou Did you recognize that the 2nd sample did provide the exact same output like the first? This is no accident - I didn't seed the `rand()` and hence it is reproducible. This might be welcome or not. In the latter case, you have to use `srand()` with a a random value (e.g. current seconds of time).

Comment: Okay, I see, for now rand() is okay (the teacher required it). Thanks for the information and for everything you were most helpful :)